# How to extract src attibute of a HTML tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string in HTML format

```
<div class="ExternalClass6FC23FEAF7454B3A8006CF7E1D2257B8">
<audio src="/sites/audioblogs/Group2Doc/0.021950338035821915.wav"   controls="controls"></audio><br/><img   src="/sites/audioblogs/Group2Doc/20140103_152938.jpg" alt=""/></div>
```

I need only the source(src) attribute,
I'm trying to use Regex.Match,

Is there any other alternative?

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. yes, i just need the list of "src" attributes in the particular string

Comment: Is the source always this simpe? Because extracting from arbitrary HTML is a very different question.

Comment: Yes the source is in the same format, But we might have multiple tags with src attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML, not regex:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);  // html is your string
var audio = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("audio")
    .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Attributes["src"] != null);
string src = null;
if (audio != null)
    src = audio.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Result: `/sites/audioblogs/Group2Doc/0.021950338035821915.wav`

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply,Can i find multiple src tags in this? Since my HTML contains multiple src tags

Comment: @SachinKothari: you mean multiple `audio` tags with a `src`? Then use: `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @SachinKothari: if you need need the `List<string>` with all src-attributes(as suggested by the first version of your title): `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("audio").Where(n => n.Attributes["src"] != null).Select(n => n.Attributes["src"].Value).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourFullHtmlstring = ".....";
//will make sure all of your double quotes are single quotes
yourFullHtmlstring= yourFullHtmlstring.Replace("\"", "'");

//will turn it into array
string[] arr = yourFullHtmlstring.Split( new string[] {"src='"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

//this will trim the sources found only to the source value.
//start from 1 because we skip the first entry before the first src
for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i].Substring(0, arr[i].IndexOf("'"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, maybe to one case, where the string "src='" is used not as a html src attribute... but it will take all sources from all html, not just from "audio".
(I think that's what he wants)